# why "match" didn't match exact code in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

when I write a Display impl for enum, I write code without enum Type, no matter what value I give in the test, it always match the first one, why ?

I find if I specify the type Phase::Add, then it could success, but why?

this will fail the test:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Phase {
    Add,
    Modify,
    Delete,
}

impl fmt::Display for Phase {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Add => write!(f, "Add"),
            Modify => write!(f, "Modify"),
            Delete => write!(f, "Delete"),
            _ => write!(f, "Unknown"),
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_lifecycle_phase() {
    let mut phase = Phase::Modify;
    assert_eq!("Modify", phase.to_string());
    phase = Phase::Delete;
    assert_eq!("Delete", phase.to_string());
}
```

Only write like this can be ok, why?

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Phase {
    Add,
    Modify,
    Delete,
}

impl fmt::Display for Phase {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Phase::Add => write!(f, "Add"),
            Phase::Modify => write!(f, "Modify"),
            Phase::Delete => write!(f, "Delete"),
            _ => write!(f, "Unknown"),
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_lifecycle_phase() {
    let mut phase = Phase::Modify;
    assert_eq!("Modify", phase.to_string());
    phase = Phase::Delete;
    assert_eq!("Delete", phase.to_string());
}
```

Comment: not same, my code didn't report compile error

Comment: Your code has many many warnings though.

Comment: @macarton haha，yeah，i'm new to rust, so come to find some help from you

Comment: If you'd like to see an error, just add this `#![deny(unreachable_patterns)]` line and your code won't compile.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited the other question so it has the warning message you get by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common pitfall. It's because `Add => ...` does not refer to `Phase::Add` but binds the value of `self` to the new variable `Add`. The name `Add` is just coincidental, yet the pattern `Phase::Add` and the (new) variable `Add` are completely different constructs. Since the variable `Add` has no pattern restrictions it always matches; the variables `Modify` and `Delete` remain unused.

As you found out yourself, you need to use `Phase::Add`, not `Add`.